# Mapping WordPress plugin data on Google Tag Manager dataLayer

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, stripe-payments, google-tag-manager

I am using the Give Donation WP plugin for a charitable website. The Stripe Payment add-on has also been integrated to allow Credit Card donations on our site. The client has tasked me to map this data on the dataLayer array of the Google Tag Manager. After filling out the form, the plugin generates the following arguments.

- donor
- date
- total_donation
- donation
- donation_status
- donation_id
- payment_key
- payment_method

How can I populate the dataLayer with these arguments. Here is the dataLayer syntax.

```js
dataLayer = [{
    'transactionId': 'payment_key',
    'transactionTotal': total_donation, 
    'event':'transactionComplete',
    'transactionProducts': [{
        'sku': 'donation_id', 
        'name': 'donor', 
        'price': total_donation, 
        'quantity': 1 
    },{
        'sku': 'donation_id', 
        'name': 'donor', 
        'price': total_donation, 
        'quantity': 1
    }] 
}];
```

I tried many ways such as adding php scripts in the dataLayer withoutany luck. These arguments can be found in 'wp-content/plugins/give/templates/shortcode-receipt.php' file. They are generated in a shortcode [give_receipt] which you can place on any WordPress. I entered the entire shortcode and I did get the results but along with the unnecessary HTML tags.

How can I populate these give plugin variables on GTM dataLayer. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is **total_donation** is not defined.